sqlalchemy-citext is not compatible with psycopg(3)
I need to use sqlalchemy-citext extension to deal with my models but I can't get it to work with psycopg (v3).
App throws an ERROR on startup:
0.258 import psycopg2.extensions
0.258 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'


I've below packages installed:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
psycopg = {extras = ["binary", "pool"], version = "3.1.13"}
sqlalchemy = {extras = ["asyncio"], version = "^2.0.31"}
sqlalchemy-citext = "^1.8.0"
...

According to info I've found sqlalchemy-citext == 1.8.0 is compatible with psycopg >= 3
I've also tried using DOCKER. The result is the same.
from python

RUN python -m pip install -U pip psycopg sqlalchemy-citext

RUN python -c "import citext"


https://github.com/mahmoudimus/sqlalchemy-citext/issues/26

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/9416

The code init,py explains it, import psycopg2.extensions.  If you want to use it then install psycopg2.

sqlalchemy-citext has not been updated in over 3 years (March 2021).
Native support for CITEXT was added in SQLAlchemy 2.0.7 and bug-fixed in 2.0.19.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.CITEXT

Initially I tried to import CITEXT from sqlalchemy the same as INT, STR or UUID.
turns out to import CITEXT we do:
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.types import CITEXT
A bit offtopic but can be useful for others.
CITEXT extension needs to be created in the database. As I use alembic I had to manually add below line to my migration file.
op.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext')
